# CLLocationManager authorization message

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

Hello i am using CLLocation to my app and i have initialise my CLLocationManager like this:

```
func initLocationManager(){    
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    let authstate = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    if(authstate == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined || authstate == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied){
        println("Not Authorised")
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() 
}
```

And i have also added the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key to my plist.

The first time i open my app i get the prompt message that my app want to access location and it has 2 buttons allow and dont allow. if i click on the dont allow button and close the app, when i opened it again i dont get the prompt message again.

How can i make this prompt message to appear each time the user opens the app? Thank you

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible. This system prompt is showing only the first time. Then it won't appear anymore. You can display your custom alert to tell user to go to settings and enable location services for your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Prompting alert each time is not a valid approach.
2. For an alternative you can show alert only in that case when **Location Service** is
   **disabled** or "**Dont Allow**" initially.
3. Following code promt alert at first and a custom alert when **Location Service** is **Disabled**

   ```
   import UIKit

   import CoreLocation

   class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {    

       var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           initLocationManager()


           // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       }

       override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
           super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
           // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
       }

       func initLocationManager(){

           let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

           if(status == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined) {
               locationManager = CLLocationManager()
               locationManager.delegate = self
               locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters

               let iosVersion = NSString(string: UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion).doubleValue

               if iosVersion >= 8.0 {
                   //For Foreground
                   locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
               }
               locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

           } else {
               if(status != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse) {


                   var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Location", message: "Please turn on Location Services", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel")
                   alert.addButtonWithTitle("Open Setting")
                   alert.show()

                   /*Add Action on Open Setting alertbutton to directly open settings in iOS 8 and later

                   ->    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)*/

               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: how this let authstate = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() will give as either .AuthorizeWhenInUse or .AuthorizedAlways the first time if we not request for authorization?

Comment: the status on the first time is notdetermined

Comment: @PanayiotisIrakleous Yes you are right . Please check the updated code.and let me know if its full fill what you needed.

Comment: now the second time i cant get location because the location manager never get instanciate

Comment: When you open app first time location manager is instantiating and after then prompt is coming. Can you please let me explain in which case of yours it is not instantiating.

Comment: when i run the app i get the prompt and i press the allow button but the location manager returns error and the second time the status is AuthorizedWhenInUse and it shows the alert that you have int the second if statment

Comment: If you are saying status is AuthorizedWhenInUse then there will not be any alert. I show alert only when it's neither AuthorizedWhenInUse nor AuthorizedAlways. Please check you have defined locationManager properly. Now For your help I have copied my whole code of ViewController.m and its running totally perfect. Please make sure you have include NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in your .plist file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84264/discussion-between-panayiotis-irakleous-and-bhu-one-bhatt).

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of doing it once the user *declines*, you have to show a dialog explaining to the user that he/she has to go to Settings and manually allow the functionality.

Comment: Michal just read the question carefully first he wants first time then not to give permission and again he opens the app prompt doesn't show again on screen.

Comment: **How can i make this prompt message to appear each time the user opens the app?** -- I'm afraid *you* need to read carefuly. The OP is asking how to show it next time *again* even though it gets **declined before**.

Answer (score 0):

This message is asking for the permission to use GPS of your device and try to getting location of the device that's why GPS is much needed on. For second you don't want to show it you can make a condition with NSUseDefaults and store a key then don't call the method locationmanager startupdatinglocation. This is the only way to don't show it again otherwise it will show everytime.

Comment: This isn't fully accurate. If the user declines, the dialog won't show again and `requestPermission` will return `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied`. Then you can't show the dialog again - you have to ask the user to manually set it in Settings.